# Remove elements from array1 that are in array2

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays that looks like this:

```
$array1 = array(
    'peter@example.com' => array(
        'peter' => 'Smith',
    ),
    'john@example.com' => array(
        'john' => 'Smith',
    ),
    'louis@example.com' => array(
        'louis' => 'Smith',
    ),
    'jane@example.com' => array(
        'jane' => 'Smith',
    ),
);


$array2 = array(
    '0' => 'peter@example.com',
    '1' => 'john@example.com',
);
```

How do I remove the array elements in array1 that match array2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$diff = array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
```

Comment: If I saw this reply I should haven't replied in this question (:

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy (but not as quick and easy as deceze's method, lol)

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
        if ($key == $array2[$i]) {
            unset($array1[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```